# Laravel - Message Toastr, on Error or Invalid Input Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this message notification when I add, edit, and delete but when the error on the field for example, I leave the textbox empty then the error will pop up, but the error is not a toast it is a `div class="alert alert-danger>`.  Can you help me on how to convert this into toastr?

Here is my error on `messages.blade.php`

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

I have this `toastr` working on my scripts and `success`, `info` are working prettty well, but the error as I said is not working.

```
<script 
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js">
</script>

<script>
    @if(Session::has('message'))
       var type="{{Session::get('alert-type','info')}}"

        switch(type){
            case 'info':
                toastr.info("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
            case 'success':
                toastr.success("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
            case 'warning':
                toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
                break;
            case 'error':
               toastr.error("{{ Session::get('message') }}");
               break;
        }
    @endif
</script>
```

My controller:

Here is where I return my view when the page is successfully created:

```
$notification = array(
    'message' => 'Employee Information Created!',
    'alert-type' => 'success'
);
    
return redirect('/admin/employeemaintenance/show')
            ->with( $notification, 'Employee Information Created');
```

How to solve this?

Comment: In order for `error` to work you'll need to send `'alert-type' => 'error'`

Comment: can you give the code? there are many alert on my code im confused sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to toast errors, I think the simplest way might be to swap the `alert-danger` for a toastr:

```
<script>
    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            toastr.error("{{ $error }}");
        @endforeach
    @endif
</script>
```

You will probably want to setup the toastr to prevent duplicates:

```
toastr.options = {
    "preventDuplicates": true
}
```

Comment: check your console, also make sure you actually have validation errors.

Comment: okay its working now just a matter of changed of places in code ;) thanjs

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help